# как убрать тэги при выводе в GridView::widget

Tags: yii2

Не нашёл на просторах интернета.
У меня при выводе виджета GridView на странице выводятся тэги как их убрать

```
 echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' =>... // и тд
        [   
           'attribute' => 'mes',
           'value' => function($model)
           {
                if($model->anons != ''){                        
                    return '<a href="">Текст ссылки</a>';
                }
                else{
                    return '--';
                }

           },

        ], 

 Во view Выводит весь код <a href="">Текст ссылки</a>
```

Comment: с yii не работал, но судя повсему вы просто выводите текст. А нужно вывести как я понимаю ссылку. для этого нужно что-то вроде этого: `Html::a('Линк', 'http://ya.ru/');`. Почитайте про html хелперы

Comment: К сожалению это тоже не помогло ( Выводит <a href="http://ya.ru/">Ли... Но спасибо за участие!

Comment: сделали `return Html::a('Линк', 'http://ya.ru/');` так? без кавычек?

Comment: без кавычек ошибка будет это же string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не указали `format`

```
'attribute' => 'mes',
'format' => 'raw',
'value' => function($model)
{
    return Html::a('text', 'https://you-url.ru');
},
```